# Filling a list with random bytes

Tags: c#, .net, list, random, byte

I'm trying to fill a buffer with random bytes. The buffer is defined as a list of bytes. This is something that I want to keep as it is. Here is the definition:

```
namespace NameofProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    List<byte> buff = new List<byte>();
    }

}
```

And  my first attempt is

```
public static void RandomFillBuffer()
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   rnd.NextBytes(buff);
}
```

Yet this gives such an error for buff:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.buff'

Then I just deleted the word "static" (I am not sure whether this is true) and it becomes "public void RandomFillBuffer()", but this time I am getting this error for buff:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'byte[]'

I'd appreciate any help to solve any of the 2 errors if they make sense.

Comment: Congratulations on being one of the few first time posters that does it correctly!

Answer (score 5):

You're getting that problem because `NextBytes()` expects an array, but you're trying to pass a `List<>`. One way to solve it would be to change your `List<>` to an array:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[someSize];
```

You're going to have to figure out what `someSize` should be (it's up to you). You can't fill something without it having a size. Otherwise, how would it know when it's done?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having is that NextBytes fills an array[] not a list. You need to define an array with an index of its size

```
    // Put random bytes into this array.
    byte[] array = new byte[8];
    // Fill array with random bytes.
    Random random = new Random();
    random.NextBytes(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

First: you tried to make your method [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) (it means that this method is not associated with any instance of the object but instead with the class of objects), and tried to reference not static member from it (your `buff` is not `static` and thus is associated with a particular instance, a particular `Form` in your case).
Second: you tried to use `Random.NextBytes(System.Byte[])` but provided `System.Collections.Generics.List<System.Byte>` as an argument.

The code below should work for you (this code assumes at least that `buff` already has some data and so has a positive length):

```
var generator = new Random();
var array = new Byte[buff.Count]; // create a local array of the same size as your list
generator.NextBytes(array); // fill the array with random bytes
buff = array.ToList(); // copy array to a new list and let field "buff" reference this freshly created list
```

Please, note, that this code is not optimal because it copies an array. But it does what you want, I guess.